# S3 CloudWatch Metrics for current and non-current objects separately

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to track size of the current and non-current objects separately.
Did I overlook something, or that is not possible?

Comment: Can you explain a bit the question? What do you mean by current and non current objects?

Comment: Non current are versioned objects which are not current. So overwritten or deleted. AWS term for those objects is “non-current”

Comment: You haven't overlooked. There isn't any metric for versioned objects.